# How to make a specific letter or part of an anchor tag linking to the href in a responsive dropdown menu

Tags: html

I'm new to webdevelopment and I am creating a responsive dropdown navigation bar with Jekyll and I followed this wonderful tutorial by [Tania Rascia](https://www.taniarascia.com/responsive-dropdown-navigation-bar/).

The problem is that there are no hrefs in Tanias tutorial so when you click on an item you don't get redirected to the specific page. Which of course is not a problem because you can just insert your own hrefs.

But I have a specific problem with the dropdown menus. Since all the dropdown menus open up when you click on them you also automatically click on the href which brings you to the specific page even though you just want to see the dropdown items. I know that I can just stop using an href and there wouldn't be a problem but I want the possibility to actually click on "Services" or "Portfolio" and get on a page that lists those items. Tania made this little Unicode arrow as an indicator that you can click the link to open up the dropdown (It's in the SCSS).

I made my own [codepen](https://codepen.io/maltede/pen/vPKzYa) where you can see my problem. If you click on the dropdown menu "Services" or "Portfolio" you will get redirected to wikipedia.org instead of seeing the dropdown items.

```
<a href="https://www.wikipedia.org">Services</a>
```

Is there a possibility that I only open the href when I click on the word itself (For example "Services") and otherwise if I click the surrounding background or the little arrow I open the dropdown-menu? If it's not possible which is the common way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the  js display the dropdown & redirect, all you have to do is to add a html tag and redirect by it.

Here's your codepen with the needed modification https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NJrZwE

```
Js part
$('#wiki').on('click', () => {
   document.location.href = "https://en.wikipedia.org";
});

Html part
<a href="#!"><span id="wiki">Portfolio</span></a>
      <ul class="nav-dropdown">
...
```